# Postfix won't forward email using virtual_alias_domains and virtual_alias_maps

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, mail-forwarding

Here is what i did:

- apt-get install postfix
- picked "internet mail"
- added a file "virtual" and appended a list with emails and emails (see below for sample)
- when changing postfix, i always updated the virtual db ( with command) and reloaded + restarted the postfix service
- example.com has a A-Record to the correct IP (hosting + Mailserver on the same server). (Also, Telnet connection doesn't give an error when connecting)

Example of the virtual file

```
 a_random_email@example.com my_email@gmail.com
 a_random_email_2@example.com my_email_2@gmail.com
```

Here's what i didn't do (and it's not required) i suppose:

- Did not create a ubuntu user per email (that's why i'm using virtual domains)

This is the contents of postconf -n

```
root@Host-Wordpress-01:~# postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
home_mailbox = mail/
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = example.com, Host-Wordpress-01, localhost.localdomain, localhost
myhostname = example.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_alias_domains = example.com
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

I don't understand why, but i have one emailaddress that CAN mail to myselve (the forward = the sender mail). All other situations aren't working.

For example, when my virtual file contains:

```
a_random_email@example.com my_email@gmail.com
```

When i mail from my_email@gmail.com to a_random_email@example.com, then it gets into the inbox of my_email@gmail.com... Weird :s

There is no email in the postfix queue

I have already search through serverfault to find relevant questions, i haven't found any that solves my issue...

I'd like to solve this but an alternative for postfix ( if simple) is also accepted.. ( haven't found any though)

Comment: Please post the `maillog` entry when you send email to alias address. Also, it would be nice to post the output of `postconf -n` instead the content of `main.cf`

Comment: replaced main.cf with postconf -n, but nothing is in my log of postfix ( /var/log/mail.log and the errors in /var/log/mail.err are when i adjusted the settings with small errors and tried reloading postfix)

Comment: Well, if there are no entry on mail.log then email is never coming to your server and postfix can't forward/alias your email. When telnet-ing  port 25, can you find some entry recorded in mail.log? Of course it would be helpful if you **disclose the real domain name**. See [What information should I include or obfuscate in my posts?](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/218590)

Comment: The real domain is moederpupegaele.be and telnet works when i mail to juice@moederpupegaele.be ( created this as a temp address). In most cases it just doesn't get delivered

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `example.com` from `mydestination` as mail to domains in that list is delivered via the `$local_transport` mail delivery transport. This is so common mistake it is separately warned in [Postfix main.cf file format](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mydestination) documentation of parameter **mydestination**:

> Warnings:
>
> Do not specify the names of virtual domains - those domains are
>   specified elsewhere. See [VIRTUAL_README](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html) for more information.

You can follow the mentioned documentation, but AFAIK the configuration seems otherwise ok.